# Regex pattern to match groups starting with pattern

Tags: regex, c#-4.0

I am extract data from a text stream which is data structured as such

```
/1-<id>/<recType>-<data>..repeat n times../1-<id>/#-<data>..repeat n times..
```

In the above, the "/1" field precedes the record data which can then have any number of following fields, each with choice of `recType` from 2 to 9 (also, each field starts with a "/")

For example:

```
 /1-XXXX/2-YYYY/9-ZZZZ/1-AAAA/3-BBBB/5-CCCC/8=NNNN/9=DDDD/1-QQQQ/2-WWWW/3=PPPP/7-EEEE
```

So, there are three groups of data above

```
 1=XXXX 2=YYYY  9=ZZZZ
 1=AAAA 3=BBBB  5=CCCC  8=NNNN  9=DDDD
 1=QQQQ 2=WWWW  3=PPPP  7=EEEE
```

Data is for simplicity, I know for certain that its only contains [A-Z0-9. ] but can be variable length (not just 4 chars as per example)

Now, the following expression sort of works, but its only capturing the first 2 fields of each group and none of the remaining fields...

```
/1-(?'fld1'[A-Z]+)/((?'fldNo'[2-9])-(?'fldData'[A-Z0-9\. ]+))
```

I know I need some sort of `quantifier` in there somewhere, but I do not know what or where to place it.

Comment: What tool or language are you using?

Comment: Visual Studio - C# .Net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex to match these blocks using 2 .NET regex features: 1) capture collection and 2) multiple capturing groups with the same name in the pattern. Then, we'll need some Linq magic to combine the captured data into a list of lists:

```
(?<fldNo>1)-(?'fldData'[^/]+)(?:/(?<fldNo>[2-9])[-=](?'fldData'[^/]+))*
```

**Details**:

- `(?<fldNo>1)` - Group `fldNo` matching `1`
- `-`  - a hyphen
- `(?'fldData'[^/]+)` - Group "fldData" capturing 1+ chars other than `/`
- `(?:/(?<fldNo>[2-9])[-=](?'fldData'[^/]+))*` - zero or more sequences of:

  - `/` - a literal `/`
  - `(?<fldNo>[2-9])` - `2` to `9` digit (Group "fldNo")
  - `[-=]` - a `-` or `=`
  - `(?'fldData'[^/]+)`- 1+ chars other than `/` (Group "fldData")

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3CfldNo%3E1%29-%28%3F%27fldData%27%5B%5E%2F%5D%2B%29%28%3F%3A%2F%28%3F%3CfldNo%3E%5B2-9%5D%29%5B-%3D%5D%28%3F%27fldData%27%5B%5E%2F%5D%2B%29%29*&i=%2F1-XXXX%2F2-YYYY%2F9-ZZZZ%2F1-AAAA%2F3-BBBB%2F5-CCCC%2F8%3DNNNN%2F9%3DDDDD%2F1-QQQQ%2F2-WWWW%2F3%3DPPPP%2F7-EEEE), results:

[image]

See [C# demo](http://ideone.com/63zheZ):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var str = "/1-XXXX/2-YYYY/9-ZZZZ/1-AAAA/3-BBBB/5-CCCC/8=NNNN/9=DDDD/1-QQQQ/2-WWWW/3=PPPP/7-EEEE";
        var res = Regex.Matches(str, @"(?<fldNo>1)-(?'fldData'[^/]+)(?:/(?<fldNo>[2-9])[-=](?'fldData'[^/]+))*")
            .Cast<Match>()
            .Select(p => p.Groups["fldNo"].Captures.Cast<Capture>().Select(m => m.Value)
                    .Zip(p.Groups["fldData"].Captures.Cast<Capture>().Select(m => m.Value), 
                        (first, second) => first + "=" + second))
            .ToList(); 
            foreach (var t in res)
                Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", t));
    }
}
```

Comment: I wish I could give more than one upvote ... just for the completeness of the answer

Comment: Please do not upvote more than 2 answers of one and the same person per day, that is considered mass upvoting and the actions are reverted the next day. One upvote per answer is enough.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to first split the string by `/1`, then use a patern along these lines:

`\/([1-9])[=-]([A-Z]+)`

https://regex101.com/r/0nyzzZ/1

Answer (score 0):

A single regex isn't the optimal tool for doing this (at least used in this way). The main reason is because your stream has a variable number of entries in it, and using a variable number of capture groups is not supported. I also noticed some of the values had "=" between them as well as the dash, which your current regex doesn't address.

The problem comes when you try and add a quantifier to a capture group - the group will only remember the last thing it captured, so if you add a quantifier, it will end up catching the first and last fields, leaving out all the rest of them. So something like this won't work:

```
\/1-(?'fld1'[A-Z]+)(?:\/(?'fldNo'[2-9])[-=](?'fldData'[A-Z]+))+
```

If your streams were all the same length, then a single regex could be used, but there's a way to do it using a foreach loop with a much simpler regex working on each part of your stream (so it verifies your stream as well when it goes along!)

Now I'm not sure what language you're working with when using this, but here is a solution in PHP that I think delivers what you need.

```
function extractFromStream($str) 
{
    /*
     * Get an array of [num]-[letters] with explode. This will make an array that
     * contains [0] => 1-AAAA, [1] => 2-BBBB ... etc
     */

    $arr    = explode("/", substr($str, 1));

    $sorted = array();
    $key    = 0;

    /*
     * Sort this data into key->values based on numeric ordering.
     * If the next one has a lower or equal starting number than the one before it, 
     * a new entry will be created. i.e. 2-aaaa => 1-cccc will cause a new
     * entry to be made, just in case the stream doesn't always start with 1.
     */

    foreach ($arr as $value) 
    {   
        // This will get the number at the start, and has the added bonus of making sure
        // each bit is in the right format.
        if (preg_match("/^([0-9]+)[=-]([A-Z]+)$/", $value, $matches)) {
            $newKey = (int)$matches[1];
            $match  = $matches[2];
        } else
            throw new Exception("This is not a valid data stream!");

        // This bit checks if we've got a lower starting number than last time.
        if (isset($lastKey) && is_int($lastKey) && $newKey <= $lastKey)
            $key += 1;

        // Now sort them..
        $sorted[$key][$newKey] = $match;

        // This will be compared in the next iteration of the loop.
        $lastKey = $newKey;
    }

    return $sorted;
}
```

Here's how you can use it...

```
$full = "/1-XXXX/2-YYYY/9-ZZZZ/1-AAAA/3-BBBB/5-CCCC/8=NNNN/9=DDDD/1-QQQQ/2-WWWW/3=PPPP/7-EEEE";

try {
    $extracted = extractFromStream($full);
    $stream1   = $extracted[0];
    $stream2   = $extracted[1];
    $stream3   = $extracted[2];

    print "<pre>";
    echo "Full extraction: \n";
    print_r($extracted);
    echo "\nFirst Stream:\n";
    print_r($stream1);
    echo "\nSecond Stream:\n";
    print_r($stream2);
    echo "\nThird Stream:\n";
    print_r($stream3);
    print "</pre>";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

This will print

```
Full extraction: 
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [1] => XXXX
            [2] => YYYY
            [9] => ZZZZ
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [1] => AAAA
            [3] => BBBB
            [5] => CCCC
            [8] => NNNN
            [9] => DDDD
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [1] => QQQQ
            [2] => WWWW
            [3] => PPPP
            [7] => EEEE
        )

)

First Stream:
Array
(
    [1] => XXXX
    [2] => YYYY
    [9] => ZZZZ
)

Second Stream:
Array
(
    [1] => AAAA
    [3] => BBBB
    [5] => CCCC
    [8] => NNNN
    [9] => DDDD
)

Third Stream:
Array
(
    [1] => QQQQ
    [2] => WWWW
    [3] => PPPP
    [7] => EEEE
)
```

So you can see you have the numbers as the array keys, and the values they correspond to, which are now readily accessible for further processing. I hope this helps you :)